# Sync two postgres databases from two sperate locations with no network

Tags: postgresql, replication, data-synchronization

I have 2 postgres databases running the same schemes on two different computers, that are not guaranteed to have any network connection while having to handle read/write requests.

Because they operate on two different locations, I'm trying to find a solution to merge them once in a while to keep data updated in both (I can connect them every couple of week, or pass files with a flash drive).

My main concern is that this databases have unique values in some of the tables (Auto Increment Primary Keys), and I'm not sure how to handle this - what if both dbs create the same key, for different data? Are there any tools that can merge automatically and output changes that were done?

(If it matters, using postgres 10, ubuntu env.)

Thanks

Comment: Have a look a [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804779/how-to-check-difference-between-two-databases-in-postgresql) SO question, at [this](https://www.altova.com/diffdog/database-compare-tool) tool or [this](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/postgresql/datacompare/)

Comment: Are you trying to have just one schema on each server with combined data in every table?  Or have have a "my schema" and an "other schema" and then use UNION ALL or inheritance to combine them when you want them combined?

Comment: @jjanes I've similar scenario where 2 different DBs, but with minor changes in schema, are required to sync. Mostly, they've same values in the `name` field but possibly not the same `PKs`. What would you suggest for this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a good way to do that is to have sequences with an increment of 2 instead of 1. That way your primary keys will be uneven on one site and even on the other one. Then you can merge without worrying.

```
create sequence seq_uneven increment by 2 start with 1;
create sequence seq_even increment by 2 start with 2;
```

And then you use `seq_uneven` on one site and `seq_even` on the other.

Comment: Thanks, it's really good for me right now. But, can you think of something that will be scaleable? Say if I'll have 10, 1000, 100000 workstations that need this mechanism?

Comment: First, I'lm sure you don't want 1000000 workstations in that kind of a situation... 
That solution work for quite small number of workstations that must be defined at the beginning.

If you want to change the number of workstations involved easily, I think you'd need UUID (see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/datatype-uuid.html).

Comment: You can't always get what you want :) Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your main concern is pretty simple, at least conceptually.  Make your sequence-based columns be bigint or bigserial, and then start your sequences so far apart that they will never overlap within any conceivable time frame.  If these values get exposed to users as, for example, invoice numbers, then you may have to compromise so that they don't overlap within any practical time frame.